# Data too large ElasticSearch issue along with Readiness probe failed

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, efk

We have set up an EFK stack for our project and from yesterday kibana seems down. When we initially troubleshooter we have found the following errors:

`Readiness probe failed: Error: Got HTTP code 503 but expected a 200` & `Readiness probe failed: Error: Got HTTP code 000 but expected a 200`

Later we found the same issue with **elasticsearch** pod as well. along with this we found the following issue with **Data request limit**:

> FATAL
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[parent]
> Data too large, data for [indices:admin/template/get] would be
> [1036909172/988.8mb], which is larger than the limitof
> [1020054732/972.7mb], real usage: [1036909056/988.8mb], new bytes
> reserved: [116/116b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=420/420b,
> in_flight_requests=67310/65.7kb, model_inference=0/0b,
> eql_sequence=0/0b,
> accounting=110294544/105.1mb]","bytes_wanted":1036909172,"bytes_limit":1020054732,"durability":"PERMANENT"}],"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[parent]
> Data too large, data for [indices:admin/template/get] would be
> [1036909172/988.8mb], which is larger than the limit of
> [1020054732/972.7mb], real usage: [1036909056/988.8mb], new bytes
> reserved: [116/116b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=420/420b,
> in_flight_requests=67310/65.7kb, model_inference=0/0b,
> eql_sequence=0/0b,
> accounting=110294544/105.1mb]","bytes_wanted":1036909172,"bytes_limit":1020054732,"durability":"PERMANENT"},"status":429}

We have tried changing the REDINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT, Initial Delay, Timeout, Probe Period, Success Threshold, and Failure Threshold. Also tried increasing the Indicess Breaker limit but it's not reflecting we can see error still taking old limits, tried fixing circuit_breaking_exception by adding ES_JAVA_OPTS values as well.

Nothing seems to be working, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the same phenomenon occurred during the service operation. This issue is identified as a memory shortage. So there are several ways to think about it over.

1. Physical Memory Expansion (Scale Out)
   Additional equipment due to insufficient memory available
2. Lower load through monitoring
   If circuit_breaking_exception remains in the log, develop a monitoring device that lowers the load
3. Setting java_opts
   You can set memory usage, but it's meaningless if you don't have enough hardware memory